# Ace js replace text

Tags: javascript

i got a problem with ace.js. I need to select a word an then insert the word without the occurance of =. This is my code:

```
editor.$search.setOptions({needle: '[A-z,0-9,_,\-]*="[A-z,0-9,_,\-,.]*"', regExp:true});
            ranges = editor.$search.findAll(editor.session);
            randomRange = ranges[Math.floor(Math.random() * ranges.length)];
            if (randomRange){
                editor.selection.setRange(randomRange);
                var content = editor.session.getTextRange(editor.getSelectionRange());
                alert(content);
                var result = content.replace('=', ''); 
                alert(result);
                editor.replace(result); 
            }
```

It selects a random occurance of that text. Then i replace the = with a space. But ace.js always replaces the text with the second occurance of the matched element, not with the first selected. Any suggestions? TY!

UPDATE: example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
```

it selects version="1.0", deletes the =. then it´s version"1.0"

but now when i call the function editor.replace(result), it replaces  PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" with that text so then its:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder version"1.0" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GOT IT! 
this should be the replace statement:

```
editor.session.replace(editor.selection.getRange(), result);
```